# How many John Doe users does Stack Overflow have?

Tags: discussion

This may be more a question related to the reuse of user names than anything else, but in the past 4 or years of so I have repeatedly helped users named `"John Doe"` all with rep of less than 10. Sometime is seems every 60 days or so. Is this the same user, or is this the same user name that has been reused?

It matters in being able to refer "John Doe" to an earlier similar question he (or she) asked when addressing the current question.

Most recent example [how to use scanf to read an integer from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488243/how-to-use-scanf-to-read-an-integer-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Unless they share the same user ID, they are likely not the same person. John Doe is a generic "unnamed" person (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe)

Comment: Not as many as "John Smith".  Yup, hate that guy.  Doesn't matter that much, he's obvious.

Comment: Thanks, it is just awkward when you see a user name repeated often and you have no easy way to determine if this is the same "John Doe" or same "John Smith" as the other without some global search of the name. @Patrice thank you -- but I'm a lawyer, I'm quite familiar with the use of "John Doe" and "Jane Doe" from a linguistic and legal standpoint.

Comment: [1438](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/901842/how-many-john-doe-users-does-stack-overflow-have) as of last week's update.

Comment: Google says [291](https://www.google.com/search?q="john+doe"+site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fusers)

Comment: @DavyM and variations thereof: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/901901?username=John+Doe

Comment: we are at least sure that we have only one "john skeet"

Comment: [1594 (4*9*44 + 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=45&tab=reputation&filter=week&search=john+doe) as per SO's own "Users" search

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the crux of the issue is there is no name uniqueness imposed during registration. We can, and do, have thousands of "John Doe"'s, etc.. So the only way that you can determine if this "John Doe" is the same "John Doe" you helped earlier in order to better tailor your answer for this "John Doe" is to go to his profile: and

1. check if he (or she) has been here long enough to be the same "John Doe";
2. if so, check (I presume searching by user_id) whether he (or she) was the same "John Doe" you helped earlier; and
3. if the original question doesn't appear, you can't necessarily presume it isn't the same "John Doe" because the question may have been deleted.

From the standpoint that I should have been able to deduce the non-uniqueness in user name, the downvotes are justified. However, from the "Discussion" tag standpoint of this question, it raises a larger issue of "Why isn't name uniqueness imposed (as in done elsewhere)?"

I'll consider the question closed based on the non-uniqueness revelation, but name uniqueness may be something to consider imposing to avoid just this type of uncertainty when helping answer questions.

Thanks to all that replied, and I would encourage going easy on "Discussion" questions (I know I do) for fear of discouraging future questions that may very well be helpful to the site, but will remain unasked.

Comment: What would happen to all the usernames that aren’t unique? A mass change of usernames would cause millions of comment @s to no longer match names.

Comment: "it raises a larger issue of 'Why isn't name uniqueness imposed (as in done elsewhere)?'" -- If this is the kind of thing you were going for, rather than an answer to the question, then you are misunderstanding the discussion tag. The tag help says it's a "tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective." It does not say that it is the tag for over broad general topics to discuss, it still should be an actual question to be answered, just that the answers may vary depending on opinions.

Comment: No, I'm just curios after answering my question. You look at google or you look at yahoo and you have "John Doe3751", etc.. I don't care whether it is implemented here or not, but for the "Discussion" purpose of it, it is just a big "Why did these smart bunch of folks decide not to?" quandary. Nothing more, nothing less than "Discussion". Why get defensive about "Discussion" or insinuate an *ad hominem*, just discuss.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't know if having a bunch of "JohnDoe54675"s instead of "JohnDoe"s is smart. My brain tends to blend out the numbers anyway, they are nothing but noise.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin One reason the smart people here didn't implement it might be that the OP isn't seen as the only receipient of an answer on SO. Answers should benefit any user, so it doesn't matter if a question was asked by JohnDoe1 or JohnDoe2.

Comment: You keep calling it *User name* while the column in the  [database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) is called "Display name". There is a functional difference between a user name and a display name. I give you that without knowing this implementation detail the difference isn't obvious if you only take the UI as reference

Comment: As for the discussion on "Why isn't name uniqueness imposed (as in done elsewhere)", it has been asked before on MSE: [Are usernames required to be unique?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176683/are-usernames-required-to-be-unique)